# How to filter data when calculate the average?

Tags: jquery, grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource = > dataSource.Ajax()
    .Aggregates(aggregates = > {
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitsInStock).Min().Max().Count();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitsOnOrder).Average();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.ProductName).Count();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitPrice).Sum();
})
    .Group(groups = > groups.Add(p = > p.UnitsInStock))
    .Read(read = > read.Action("Aggregates_Read", "Grid"))
```

Now I want to calculate the sum  of UnitPrice without those price which <0 and background is not transparent（without color);I write the codes down,but it is wrong.

```
.DataSource(dataSource = > dataSource.Ajax()
    .Aggregates(aggregates = > {
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitsInStock).Min().Max().Count();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitsOnOrder).Average();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.ProductName).Count();
    aggregates.Add(p = > p.UnitPrice)
        .Sum(p.UnitPrice > 0 && p.background == transparent);
})
    .Group(groups = > groups.Add(p = > p.UnitsInStock))
    .Read(read = > read.Action("Aggregates_Read", "Grid"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom aggregates are not support. You can consider defining your own template and calculate ityourself, the information you will probably will need can be retrieved from the dataSource.view() or dataSource.data() methods.

[Here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/how-to-do-custom-aggregate-functions.aspx#_Mns6-Vdn0aoSfP7aW-x7g) is a post which explains just the same.